Swipe Actions on List - How to have them with corner radius?
I have a List with a plain style, like the following:
struct CustomList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(state.sections) { section in
                inboxSection(section: section)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }

    private func inboxSection(section: Section) -> some View {
        Section(header: sectionHeader(for: section)) {
            ForEach(section.elements) { element in
                ItemRow(element: element)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                        CustomButton()
                    }
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0))
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .roundedCornerWithBorder(
                        borderColor: .Light.Border.defaultColor,
                        radius: .BorderRadius.lg,
                        corners: .allCorners
                    )
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func sectionHeader(for section: ViewState.Section) -> some View {
        Text(section.headerTitle)
    }
}

struct RoundedCorner: Shape {
    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect,
            byRoundingCorners: corners,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)
        )
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

public extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }

    func roundedCornerWithBorder(
        lineWidth: CGFloat = 1,
        borderColor: Color,
        radius: CGFloat,
        corners: UIRectCorner
    ) -> some View {
        clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners))
            .overlay(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners)
                .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: lineWidth))
    }
}

which would produce something like this:

But as you see, the rows with the .swipeActions don't really take into account the corner radius of the list's rows. I tried basically everything without much luck. Does anyone know how to achieve this in SwiftUI and if it's even achievable? I can give some other examples of a better result with the weather app:

Or this other screenshot, which would also be even better:

Important note:
Other list styles like .insetGrouped do have a better swipe actions, but they'd change too much the layout, and the problem would still persist considering the requirements I have for my lists. (e.g. section header would be with caps and a different style.)

I don't think there is a "native" way to do this. You'd have to make a swipeable list row from scratch. The weather app probably did just that, and the last screenshot seems like an inset grouped list.

Using RoundedRectangle might be a less convoluted way of creating a, er, rounded rectangle. Or use UnevenRoundedRectangle if you only want to round certain corners.

Mhh but why building something from scratch and not making available? I'd be surprised... and for the second part, I also think it's an inset grouped list, but then how did they manage to have the corners on all edges? I think that could be achievable only by having sections of 1 element, I can't think of any other way. (or simply with UIKit, more likely)

if I build with RoundedRectangle, then I'd have to care for the swiping actions manually and it'd be pretty tricky.. :s

Those examples are custom or using private API (Apple) sadly. Here is a video that shows how to properly implement stuff like this, but know that its a rather large task: https://vimeo.com/865570738

I see... Thanks!
